# How to reference only the number in linear regression function

Tags: r

in r let's say I have this:
house_model is the linear regression model

```
b_0 = house_model$coefficients[1]
b_1 = house_model$coefficients[2]

print(b_0)

print(b_1)
```

and this will output

```
(Intercept) 
-1.171116 
area
0.17545795
```

So I want to only get the numbers and not the names. I want to only see -1.171116 and .17545795. is there a way to do this?

Comment: `unname(house_model$coefficients[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(unname(b0))
```

or

```
cat(b0,"\n")
```

(the `"\n"` is to add a newline character; `cat()` also skips the `[1]` at the beginning of the line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as.numeric` function as follows:

```
# without an additional variable
print(as.numeric(house_model$coefficients[1]))

# with an additional variable
print(as.numeric(b_0))
```